# How can I subtract numbers from an Array to get my total to 0. I want to skip numbers that would make my total a negative

Tags: javascript

I am not done with this project, but I am stuck in one part of the project. I am having trouble just pushing the numbers that will make my total 0. For example if the change I need to give back is 5.50 my array should be [5,.50]. My numbers in my Array should not exceed the numbers inside myArr1. I might not be phrasing the question right but any insight on how to tackle this problem would be wonderful. Thank you!

```js
function checkCashRegister(price, cash, cid) { 
  let myArr = [];
  let myChange = 0
  let change = cash-price;
  let total = cash - price
  let myArr2 = []
  let myMon =  [["PENNY", .01], ["NICKEL", .05], ["DIME",.1, ],["QUARTER", .25], ["ONE", 1],["FIVE", 5],["TEN", 10],[    "TWENTY", 20],["ONE HUNDRED", 100]]
  let myArr1 = {"PENNY":1.01, "NICKEL": 2.05,"DIME":3.1,"QUARTER": 4.25, "ONE": 90,"FIVE": 55,"TEN": 20, "TWENTY": 60,"ONE HUNDRED": 100}
  let myNum = {"PENNY":.01, "NICKEL": .05,"DIME":.1,"QUARTER": .25, "ONE": 1,"FIVE": 5,"TEN": 10, "TWENTY": 20,"ONE HUNDRED": 100}
  
for(let i =0; i <myMon.length; i++){
if(myMon[i][1] <= change){

myArr.unshift(myMon[i][1])

}
}
for(let i = 0; i<myArr.length; i++){
 myArr2.push(total -= myArr[i])
   
} 
    return myArr2

}
console.log(checkCashRegister(70, 100, [["PENNY", 1.01], ["NICKEL", 2.05], ["DIME", 3.1], ["QUARTER", 4.25], ["ONE", 90], ["FIVE", 55], ["TEN", 20], ["TWENTY", 60], ["ONE HUNDRED", 100]]));
```

Comment: You don't appear to reference either `myNum` nor `myArr1`..?

Comment: Yeah I know sorry, they are from my previous attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't work with fractions for currency.** Javascript's `Number` type is binary-based floating point only, which means some decimal fractions aren't exactly represented. See below:

```js
//working with fractions of Dollars
let change = 6.30
let dime = 0.10
let dimeCoins = change / dime //you won't get exactly 63 dimes
console.log(63, dimeCoins, 63 - dimeCoins)

//working with cents (no inexact rounding of fractional values) 
change = 630
dime = 10
dimeCoins = change / dime
console.log(63, dimeCoins, 63 - dimeCoins)
```

As for your problem model, keep in mind that *for every* **currency denomination**, the cash register has a **number of units** with the corresponding **individual value**.

When picking change, the cashier always tries to *exhaust the greatest bills* before *moving on to the lesser, next greatest ones*.

You can solve this problem using no objects, two arrays and a for loop.